# Cursor jumped while typing in excel, word or outlook

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, boot-camp

1. Cursor jumped while typing in excel, word or outlook
2. Sometimes cursor goes to end of the second while i was typing in first line.
3. Ticked the "hide pointer while typing", still issue is persisting.

Comment: What's the relevance of the `boot-camp` tag?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by trackpad sensitivity where typing causes a signal from the trackpad. If you have a trackpad, try reducing its sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Charles Kenyon. As a supplement, if necessary, please try to modify the sensitivity of trackpad by the steps in the following article: [How to Change the Sensitivity of Your TouchPad in Windows 7](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-sensitivity-touchpad-windows-7-28440.html).

If this does not work, considering the impact of some specific programs or software, it is recommended that you could try to [perform a clean boot in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd) and see if the problem persists.

In addition, I noticed that the issue occurs in the Office applications. Will this issue occur in other web or programs? If issue only occurs in Office applications, considering that the applications themselves are damaged, it is recommended that you could try to [repair the Office applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to see if there're any differences.

Hope to help you!

Comment: Is this issue resolved now? If so, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.